# Escape \u in a string

Tags: python

I have a requirement where I am supposed to store in username in database. The general format of those names is local\username. One of the username I stumbled upon is local\uat10215. I am getting the following error.

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 5-6: truncated \uXXXX escape
```

Although I understand the problem, but haven't encountered it ever before and I am unaware of what can be solution to this.

**Edit:**

This is a part of Django project that I am working on. It comes with `User` model of it's own with the username as one of the field. I have username/password combination for authentication purposes. We also have SAML based authentication where in the IdP is a third party. Now this IdP has username stored on their side and we simply keep reference to it on our application using the User model. So practically, the value of username field is not under my control and values are anything. One username value I stumbled upon yesterday was `local\uat10215`. I tried to update one user's username with this value for testing via shell, but I got the above error. If I use `r'local\uat10215'` the value that gets stored in db is `local\\uat10215` which won't match `local\uat10215`. As for reproducible code, it can simply be tried in `ipython`

[image]

Further more:

I simply wrote this function,

```
def bs_test():

    try:
        username = r'local\uat10125'
        print(username)
    except Exception as e:
        print('Exception')
```

The below is the output.

[image]

Based on this, I think it was iPython's behavior that put me off track.

Another thing that I tried is to actually store such value into database(Postgres) from iPython. I am attaching the screenshot to demo the operations carried out along with the output.

[image]

Comment: You should escape the `'\'` in your string or use the `r` string qualifier, depending on what exact code is actually giving you trouble.

Comment: Let's say I replace '\' with '\\' I am still left with local\\uat4013 which still is an issue. I tried r, it results in local\\uat4013 and hence username doesn't match.

Comment: What about posting the code giving you trouble in some sort of [mwe](/help/mcve) fashon? I do not particularly shine in divination :-P

Comment: sidenote:  Is this username considered legal in database ? if it is legal name, find the program that writes this username in database and copy its behavior; if it is illegal , delete the username and any further  names like this?

Comment: @norok2 Updated the question with more content

Comment: Not just IPython. IDLE (for example) will work the same way. The shell is for the programmer, not the end-user. The shell shows the string literal, but doesn't *display* the string unless asked to `print` it. If you aren't worried about the fact that the username itself does not actually contain surrounding single quote marks, why are you worried about the seemingly extra `\ ` inside the string literal? Neither the `'` nor the first `\ ` are characters in the string itself, but are instead symbols used by the programmer (and the shell) to specify the string. It can definitely be confusing.

Comment: When you literally type `r'local\uat10215'` in the shell, you seem to have expected the shell to in effect respond with `print(r'local\uat10215')`. Instead, what it is really doing is closer to `print(repr(r'local\uat10215'))`. [repr](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#repr) returns (as much as possible) the literal corresponding to the object. The confusion is that for a string, s, `repr(s)` is also a string -- but not quite the *same* string.

Comment: By the way -- are you *sure* about this: "If I use r'local\uat10215' the value that gets stored in db is local\\uat10215"? I don't see why `repr(r'local\uat10215')` rather than the string you want would be stored. If there is still a genuine problem here rather than a misinterpretation of what the shell output means, you would need to give a [mcve] (involving how values are stored in the database) which allows others to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @JohnColeman thanks a lot, I figured it out later that it was interpreter's behaviour that got me confused. About your question, I actually tried it on interpreter by simply assigning the value to variable and it did get stored as `local\\10215`.

Comment: @JohnColeman also later when I tried it by using a simple function in a file it worked as per the expectation. I think it's the interpreter that behaves differently. But thanks a lot for explanation. I have been working on python for good amount of time, never encountered such strings and hence the mistake on my part when dealing with it in ipython.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by the `'\u'`, which is detected as `unicodeescape`.
To solve that, there are two options:

1. Double all the back slashes (i.e `local\\uat10215`)
2. Use raw strings (i.e `r'local\uat10215'`)

Comment: An issue with 1 is that usernames won't match. When I add 'r' the resultant string is same as 1st and hence the problem persists.

Comment: Then I suggest you post some code to reproduce the error you got.

Comment: @RajeshYogeshwar `'local\\uat10215'` simply *is* the string literal corresponding to `local\uat10215`. If that doesn't work, then there is something which you are not telling us. Note that the string `'local\\uat10215'` only contains a single backslash.

Comment: @singrium Updated the question with more content

Comment: @JohnColeman Updated the question and there is nothing to hold back. Attached more screenshots for clarity and I think I have found that it is python interpreter that was putting me off track.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide an example at least of the line of code generating the error.

However I suppose you should try single quoting the raw string like this `r'local\uat10215'`

Another solution could be double escaping like `local\\uat10215` depending on your code

Comment: How would single quoting help?

Comment: you're right i forgot the r before the single quote, I'll update the answer

Comment: The `r` is the important part, not the single quotes. It'll work with double quotes or multiline quotes as well.